# How to use SQL - DATEDIFF function

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

need quick help here.

I'm coming up with a column to track how many days a event is back-logged.
So I'm using this syntax which is working

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), ESI.EventStatusDate) AS BackloggedDays
```

However, the modification I want to use is, the event status date + 3 days. Any ideas how i would add that to this syntax. Thanks

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `DATEADD()` :

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY, 3, ESI.EventStatusDate)) AS BackloggedDays
```